# I am unable to replace a special character with 0 and then in return replace that 0 with a median value of my column

Tags: python, replace, attributeerror, fillna

I have been an automobile dataset for a private project. I have '?' in my price column which I am planning to replace with a median value of the automobile companies price for different models. I am trying to achieve this by first calculating the price using groupby() and then replace the '?' values with 0. When I tried to replace the 0 with calculated median price it throws the below error:

```
**ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-a5866362d7e0> in <module>
----> 1 car['price'].replace(np.nan,med_price,inplace=True)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method)
   4507         method="pad",
   4508     ):
-> 4509         return super().replace(
   4510             to_replace=to_replace,
   4511             value=value,
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method)
   6921                     # Operate column-wise
   6922                     if self.ndim == 1:
-> 6923                         raise ValueError(
   6924                             "Series.replace cannot use dict-value and "
   6925                             "non-None to_replace"
ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-value and non-None to_replace**
```

Then I tried replacing the 0 with NaN and then using fillna() to replace those NaN with the median values. I am able to run the above fillna() command, but the changes are not taking place in the dataset. Kindly help.

Coding Part:

```
car.info()

**<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 205 entries, 0 to 204
Data columns (total 26 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   symboling          205 non-null    int64  
 1   normalized-losses  205 non-null    object 
 2   make               205 non-null    object 
 3   fuel-type          205 non-null    object 
 4   aspiration         205 non-null    object 
 5   num-of-doors       205 non-null    object 
 6   body-style         205 non-null    object 
 7   drive-wheels       205 non-null    object 
 8   engine-location    205 non-null    object 
 9   wheel-base         205 non-null    float64
 10  length             205 non-null    float64
 11  width              205 non-null    float64
 12  height             205 non-null    float64
 13  curb-weight        205 non-null    int64  
 14  engine-type        205 non-null    object 
 15  num-of-cylinders   205 non-null    object 
 16  engine-size        205 non-null    int64  
 17  fuel-system        205 non-null    object 
 18  bore               205 non-null    object 
 19  stroke             205 non-null    object 
 20  compression-ratio  205 non-null    float64
 21  horsepower         205 non-null    object 
 22  peak-rpm           205 non-null    object 
 23  city-mpg           205 non-null    int64  
 24  highway-mpg        205 non-null    int64  
 25  price              205 non-null    object** 


car['price'].replace('?',0,inplace=True)
car['price'] = car.price.astype(float) #changing from object dtype to float

med_price = car.groupby('make')['price'].agg(np.median) #median price for each maker 
car['price'].replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True)

car.head(15)

car['price'].replace(np.nan,med_price,inplace=True) #throws the above mentioned error

car['price'].fillna(value=med_price)
car.head(15) -- no changes after the above line, still can see NaN.\
```

I am sharing a snap of my dataset as well the code I have run.
Original Dataset:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJAix.png)

After replacing the 0 with Nan:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dDOZ.png)

Code screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaxIk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMq4S.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVrZu.png)

Comment: Replace all your images with text

Comment: Code:
med_price = car.groupby('make')['price'].agg(np.median)
car['price'].replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True) -- Throws error
car['price'].fillna(value=med_price) -- runs perfectly
car.head(15) -- but the NaN didnt get replace from above code

Answer (score 1):

try replacing with str() type of what you want to replace , maybe it helps ...

see , in your code screenshot I saw this :
`car['price'].replace('?' , 0 , inplace = True)`

now , I recommend using this instead :
`car['price'].replace('?' , '0' , inplace = True)`

I'm not sure it helps but worth trying .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Behrad Can you please be a bit more specific? Didn't get you.

Comment: yes man , of course . I'll edit the answer , read there